# Streamlit logic with session states

Tags: pandas, logic, session-state, streamlit

**Idea:**
Say I have 4 checkboxes with keys A, B, C, D and I also have a dataframe with A, B, C, D as indexes and all of them having some default value, like this:

```
import pandas as pd import streamlit as st

df = pd.DataFrame(index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],  columns = ['Value', 'Active'],  data = [[0, False], [0, False], [0, False], [0, False]])

df['Active'].loc['A'] = st.checkbox('A') 
df['Active'].loc['B'] = st.checkbox('B') 
df['Active'].loc['C'] = st.checkbox('C') 
df['Active'].loc['D'] = st.checkbox('D')
```

My goal is to create a data editor filtering only the "active keys" (determined by the checkboxes), this is my previous attempt:

`st.data_editor(df[df['Active'] == True]['Value'])`

So let's say we click on the checkbox "C", it should create a new row with in the data editor.

The problem is that everytime we click on the checkbox the code gets run again so it resets all values that may have been changed to the default. Example: we activate "A" and change the value to 37, but then activate "B", when "B" is activated the row "A" returns to the default value of 1, but I want it to keep 37.

I guess the solution may have something with session states but I just can't figure it out! Thanks for the attention

Comment: Please adjust your code so it's valid Python. You can [edit] the post. Thanks.